# show the image and title of the last 3 clicked image links in a php session

Tags: php, session

I`m trying to find a way to show the image and title of the last 3 clicked image links. 
Here is the construction of the links:

```
    <a href="?link=test1">
        <img src="http://www.mijncambodja.nl/?link=cambodja-phnom-penh" id="img-phnom-penh" title="phnom penh">
        <div class="disp-div">phnom penh</div>
    </a>

    <a href="?link=test2">
        <img src="http://www.mijncambodja.nl/?link=cambodja-sihanoukville" id="img-sihanoukville" title="sihanoukville">
        <div class="disp-div">sihanoukville</div>
    </a>

    <a href="?link=test3">
        <img src="http://www.mijncambodja.nl/?link=cambodja-siem-reap" id="img-siem-reap" title="siem reap">
        <div class="disp-div">siem reap</div>
    </a>

    <a href="?link=test4">
        <img src="http://www.mijncambodja.nl/?link=cambodja-kampot" id="img-kampot" title="kampot">
        <div class="disp-div">kampot</div>
    </a>

    <a href="?link=test5">
        <img src="http://www.mijncambodja.nl/?link=cambodja-kep" id="img-kep" title="kep">
        <div class="disp-div">kep</div> 
    </a>
```

So i would like to see the last 3 clicked images and titles in a session stored. Everytime a new image link is clicked, the oldest of the 3 links is destroyed.

Can someone please help me out here? If possible in    jsfiddle

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this code at the top of your page before `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

```
$click_id=filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'link', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); // Get the image ID sent by the AJAX.

if(!isset($_SESSION['clicks'])) // If the SESSION is not created already, create it.
{
  $_SESSION['clicks']=array();
}

array_unshift($_SESSION['clicks'], $click_id); // Prepend the last click ID to the SESSION array.

if(sizeof($_SESSION['clicks'])>3)
{
    array_pop($_SESSION['clicks']); // If the array size is greater than 3, delete the last index, that is the oldest value.
}
```

So you can get the last three clicks by

```
$_SESSION['clicks'][0], // Most recent click
$_SESSION['clicks'][1], // Second recent click
$_SESSION['clicks'][2], // Oldest click
```

Comment: thanks, i have to say ajax isn`t my best language. How could i send the image ID to the newly made page?

Comment: Your **link** is a separate PHP page, right? If so, you can have the new code in the top of that page.

Comment: I am sorry, I have not understood your comment fully, do you mean you cannot use AJAX or you do not have sound idea in AJAX?

Comment: sorry, i missed your second post. so your second post completely answerd my question, thanks.

Comment: my page:   http://www.mijncambodja.nl/?link=cambodja-steden  consists of php include pages.   The images are in the <?php include('includes/content.php'); ?>    part while i would like to show the clicked images in the <?php include('includes/sbr_right.php'); ?>  part

Comment: Okay I have checked your page, I will edit my answer in according to that. Please hold for a minute.

Comment: Can i repeat: So i put the first code part in my index above the <!DOCTYPE html> part and withing <script> </script> and the   most recent session code part in the include within  <script> </script>?

Comment: No put the first part code above the `<doctype html>` within `<?php ?>`. It is a PHP code. And the second part is where you need to get the last three clicked images.

Answer (score 1):

Every click should pass through PHP script.
PHP script should implement queue.
So for example (not tested):

```
class Image {
    protected $name;
    protected $title;

    public function __construct($name, $title) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getTitle() {
        return $this->title;
    }

}

class ImageQueue {

    protected static $queue = array();

    public static function addImage($title, $name) {
        $image = new Image($name, $title);
        array_shift(self::$queue);
        array_push($image);

    }

    public static function toArray() {
        $array = array();
        foreach(self::$queue as $image) {
            $array[] = array(
                'name'  => $image->getName(),
                'title' => $image->getTitle()
            );
        }

        return $array;
    }

    public static function saveToSession() {
        $_SESSION['mage_queue'] = self::toArray();
    }

}
```